# Slow while loop Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate a google spreadsheet by getting a report with several rows and different IDs like 105, 110, 112. each of them have several rows with different information and they are ordered. I created a script that iterate to each row, and if  it is equal to the previous it copies the row to a new sheet until it is different, than create a new sheet with the new ID and copy every row that contains the same ID and so on.

It works OK but it is very slow, and exceed the time of GSheets.

This is the code I am running:

```
    function reports(){
      var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Extrato');

      var criada = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('criada');


      var row  = 2;

      var cell = ss.getRange(row, 1).getValue();  

      while (cell > 0){

        var repres     = ss.getRange(row, 1);
        var a          = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, 21).copyTo(criada.getRange(criada.getLastRow()+1,1, 1, 21));
        var range      = ss.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
        var newSheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet().setName(range);
        var secRange   = ss.getRange(row-1, 1).getValue();

          while(range === secRange || secRange == "REPRES"){    
            var range = ss.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
            var secRange = ss.getRange(row-1, 1).getValue();
            if (secRange === range){
              ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, 21).copyTo(criada.getRange(criada.getLastRow()+1,1, 1, 21));
            };
            row += 1;
          };
        var copyRange = criada.getRange(1, 1, criada.getLastRow(), 21).copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1, 1));
        criada.getRange(2, 1, 500, 21).clearContent();

      };

    };
```

Does anyone could let me know a better way to write this code in order to run faster?

P.S. The report has around 17,000 rows

Thank you

This is what I need, the first pic is the report and the second is the individual report by ID.

[[image: Sample[][1][1]]

[image: Sample 2]

I also tried to get the whole range with this code, but it got through an infinite loop:

```
    function teste2() {
      var ss   = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Extrato');
      var criada = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('criada');
      var row  = 2;
      var cell = ss.getRange(row, 1).getValue();  

      while (cell > 0){
        var repres     = ss.getRange(row, 1);
        var a          = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, 21).copyTo(criada.getRange(criada.getLastRow()+1,1, 1, 21));
        var range      = ss.getRange(row, 1).getValue();
        var newSheet   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().insertSheet().setName(range);
        var secRange   = ss.getRange(row-1, 1).getValue();

          while(range === secRange || secRange == "REPRES"){   
            var row1 = row;
            var row2 = row;
            var range = ss.getRange(row2, 1).getValue();
            var secRange = ss.getRange(row2-1, 1).getValue();
            if (secRange === range){
              row2 += 1;
              Logger.log(row2);
            };
          };
        var copyRange = ss.getRange(row1, 1, row2-row1, 21).copyTo(newSheet.getRange(1, 1));
        Logger.log(row2)
        row = row2;


      };

    };
```

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue is to use `getValue` and `copyTo` in the loops. For this situation, [this document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) might be useful. By the way, when you provide a sample Spreadsheet and sample output you want, it will help users think of the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Well noted Tanaike, I've edited the post, thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Of course there is an infinite loop! You never modify `cell`, not do you have any other kind of exit condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easier way to solve this problem, I used the 'UNIQUE' formula to get every unique ID, then I created a filter to get all the information about each ID and create a new sheet based on that filter. This way it doesn't iterate each line, it gets the whole range and copies to the new sheet. I used a for loop to get each ID information. Thanks guys for taking your time trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested while loops - this makes your code slow as you noticed yourself.

### Why?

Because in both loops you call external services (SpreadsheetApp methods), and those calls are slow as you can withdraw [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

### How to optimize the code?

Replace singles requests within each loop iteration by a batch request after exiting the loops.

A general idea how to do so:

- Create a dummy array
- Before entering the loop, assign all values of the range to a value-array with `getValues()`, rather than doing it within each loop iteration with `getValue()`
- Create an empty dummy array
- Create a loop that iterates through the values of the value-array
- During each loop iteration check if your `if` condition is fullfilled, and if so - push the corresponding values into your dummy array
- After exiting the loop, use  `setValues()` instead of `setValue()`, to set all values in the dummy array at once to the corresponding range(s)

As for the outer while loop:

Given that your `row` and `cell` seems to be a fix value, replace `while (cell > 0)` by `if (cell > 0)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, before I try your suggestions I will explain why I did what I did. I have two nested while loops because I have a list of IDs, and each ID has a few rows with different informations, then I need to iterate through each ID, copy each row of this ID, and paste into a new sheet, having a sheet with all the rows that ID has. So once the script loops through the first id, it creates a new sheet and search for other ID and do the same until the cell is empty. 
I set the row value because I want to start on the second row, and then each loop will increase its value

Comment: This makes sense, but given that you have 17000 rows and want to make your code faster, you should think about changing your algorithms in such a way that you can reduce the usage of loops, and - especially - reduce the number of calls to SpreadsheetApp. Replace multiple `getValue()` and `setValue()` requests for every single row as much as possible by  `getValues()` and `setValues()` for the whole range.

Comment: I tried doing this but wasn't lucky with the code, maybe you could help me to figure that out. I will edit the post with the code I tried. Thank you